# ServiceStack, CORS, and OPTIONS (No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header)

Tags: c#, http-headers, cors, servicestack

We're hitting a bit of a snag with CORS features of a restful API in ServiceStack 4.

We want to be sneding cookies to the api since the SS session is in the cookies, so we make AJAX calles with "WithCredentials" = true in our angular clients that hit the API.

Since Chrome (at least) doesn't like Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcards with WithCredentials, we've added a pre-request filter to echo back the requester's origin in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header like so:

```
private void ConfigureCors()
            {
                Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
                    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type",
                    allowCredentials: true,
                    allowedOrigins: ""));

                PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) =>
                {
                    string origin = httpReq.Headers.Get("Origin");
                    if (origin != null)
                    {
                        httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, origin);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Add the dev localhost header.
                        httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, "http://localhost:9000");
                    }
                });

                PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) =>
                {
                    //Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
                    if (httpReq.Verb == "OPTIONS")
                    {
                        httpRes.EndRequest();
                    }
                });
            }
```

However, we're hitting a snag on OPTIONS requests, because the SS service is not emitting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header back when the request is ended. This makes Chrome reject the call.

We tried putting an explicit header inside the pre-request filter for OPTIONS, but it still doesn't return an ACAO header for OPTIONS calls:

```
 PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) =>
            {
                //Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
                if (httpReq.Verb == "OPTIONS")
                {
                    httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, "*");
                    httpRes.EndRequest();
                }
            });
```

It seems like this must have been dealt with before, but we couldn't find anything quite like this on StackOverflow.

Are we doing something wrong with the OPTIONS pre-request filter? Why does it not return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: Thankf god for your post I was going crazy with CORS. You help me with your example and by saying turn WithCredentials on with angularjs ! Thx

Answer (score 4):

You should add the whitelisted domains in the `allowOriginWhitelist`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(allowedHeaders:"Content-Type",
    allowCredentials:true,
    allowOriginWhitelist:new[]{"http://localhost:9000"}));
```

There was an issue introduced in v4.0.35 where as [PreRequestFilters were being written in Custom HttpHandlers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/709fb73c1450f13ba6449eed9101e588775c3d9d) this caused the [CorsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs) to write out the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header twice causing browsers to reject it. This has now been resolved [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/d834642137c064cf0e4ff1219dac12d405cebb2b) which is available from v4.0.36+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

This latest version has been deployed to the http://test.servicestack.net demo which shows cross-domain authentication with ServiceStack in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/korijigucu/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    var apiBase = "http://test.servicestack.net";
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {  
      $rootScope.success = "running...";
      $http
         .post(apiBase + '/auth/credentials', 
             { "UserName": "test", "Password": "test" }, 
             { withCredentials: true })
         .success(function (data) {
             $rootScope.success = "Login successful: " + JSON.stringify(data);
         })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $rootScope.error = 'ERR:login';
         });
    }]);    
  </script>
</head>
<body>    
  <div style='color:green'>{{success}}</div>
  <div style='color:red'>{{error}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Source code for the [CorsFeature registration in above Test project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/240559b9bd4ecb93c52771b4ba325ac4ca56b136/src/Test/Test/AppHost.cs#L65):

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { 
      "http://localhost", "http://localhost:56500", 
      "http://test.servicestack.net", "http://null.jsbin.com" },
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization"));
```

Comment: Using this whitelist means we heave to redeploy the service every time we add a new api consumer, right? I was hoping to avoid that with the prerequest filter, which works fine for GETs, but is not being called for OPTIONs.

Comment: @gizmoboy the whitelist collection is public so you can add it at runtime with: `HostContext.GetPlugin<CorsFeature>().AllowOriginWhitelist.Add("http://newdomain.com");`

Comment: @gizmoboy otherwise as the [CorsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs) is pretty lightweight, that using a local customized version is another potential option.

Comment: Very confused by this. The plunkr works fine, but when I try to run your $http call in our SPA, I get this error in the Chrome console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://test.servicestack.net/auth/credentials. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I tried adding the whitelist, but the OPTIONS call to auth is still not returning an access-control-allow-origin header.

Comment: @gizmoboy test.servicestack.net doesn't include `http://localhost:9000` in the whitelist, the only localhost domains specified are `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:56500`. The above example also shows that it allows cross-domain requests to `http://null.jsbin.com` when its specified in the `allowOriginWhitelist `. If you have any custom handlers/configuration that could interfere with the OPTIONS request you should remove them.

Comment: I hadn't thought that one through.  I've cloned the SS code in my apphost and am getting an ACAO header back now, but it's echoing back a wildcard origin (*) instead of localhost:9000. This is the property:  allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { "http://localhost:9000", "http://localhost", "http://www.xgauntlet.com", "https://www.xgauntlet.com" } but when angular makes the OPTIONS call for auth/credentials, SS is returning Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* (NOte: there are no semicolons in the allowOriginWhitelist property; it's being added by StackOVerflow)

Comment: @gizmoboy Sounds like you're using the wrong constructor as the constructor with `allowOriginWhitelist` [doesn't set a wildcard allowOrigin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs#L49). The [CorsFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/CorsFeature.cs) is very small and easy to follow and there's nothing else in ServiceStack that's related to CORS. You can also try using a local copy of CorsFeature so you can debug it and follow what/when it emits the CORS HTTP Headers.

Answer (score 1):

***Note:*** *Updating to 4.0.36 resolved the doubled-header issue described below, rendering the second pre-request filter obsolete.*

I finally got this to work, but it feels like a kludge.

I added the allowOriginWhitelist entry as Demis suggested, which was returning doubled values for the header (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000`), at least for OPTIONS calls (it appears to work fine for POST and GET):

```
 Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
                    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization",
                    allowCredentials: true,
                    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { "http://localhost:9000", "http://www.productiondomain.com", "https://www.productiondomain.com" }));
```

So I added the following pre-request filter, based on the earlier filter we were using:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) =>
                {
                    //Handles Request and closes Responses after emitting global HTTP Headers
                    if (httpReq.Verb == "OPTIONS")
                    {
                        string origin = httpReq.Headers.Get("Origin");
                        if (origin != null)
                        {
                            httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, origin);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Add the dev localhost header.
                            httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, "http://localhost:9000");
                        }
                        httpRes.EndRequest();
                    }
                });
```

This has resolved the issue, but it feels like a kludge. Does anyone know why this simple code would produce doubled ACAO headers in the response?

```
     Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
                    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization",
                    allowCredentials: true,
                    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { "http://localhost:9000", "http://www.productiondomain.com", "https://www.productiondomain.com" }));
```

Comment: @mythz Any idea why we were getting the doubled ACAO headers in the response when just using the CorsFeature plugin listed above without the added OPTIONS re-request filter?

Comment: Are you using the [latest v4.0.36 release on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)? My answer explained why v4.0.35 writes headers out twice and that it's resolved with the [v4.0.36 that's on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet). I don't see why you need to register your own PreRequestFilters as this is already handled in CorsFeature.

Comment: @mythz We had the latest version on NuGet, not MyGet. Updating to using the interim release on MyGet resolved the doubled-headers issue. Now auth works, but a GET to a service call after auth is not returning the ACAO header, so it's failing. The service call is trivially simple; it's practically a test call (basically, returning the user session object for an authenticated user).

Comment: @mythz Never mind; our developers found the issue; 4.0.36 update definitely resolves the problem and makes using allowOriginWhitelist a clean and viable solution. Thanks!