# CORS not allowing whitelist with Credentials=true

Tags: servicestack

Everthing has been work absolutely fine - until I upgraded to a later version of ServiceStack recently - I'm now on version 4.0.35.0

```
Public Overrides Sub Configure(container As Funq.Container)
        Dim appSettings = New AppSettings() 'Gets settings from web.config
        ...
        Plugins.Add(New CorsFeature(allowOriginWhitelist:={"http://localhost:8888", "http://site1.abc.com", "http://site2.abc.com", "http://site3.abc.com"}, allowedMethods:="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS", allowedHeaders:="Content-Type, Authorization", allowCredentials:=True))


End Sub
```

Error being received is:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://site1.abc.com/auth/credentials. 
 The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://site1.abc.com, http://site1.abc.com', 
 but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://site1.abc.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The call is being made from site1.abc.com and interestingly its saying that its in their twice - but it definately isnt.

Any clues as to what's going on
I do need multiple sites calling an API on a single endpoint with credentials.

Thanks

Terry

Comment: This issue is [fixed in v4.0.36](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27831155/85785) which is [available on MyGet now](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) and on NuGet later today.

Comment: FYI [v4.0.36 has just been released on NuGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#v4036-release-notes)

Answer (score 0):

This issue should now be resolved with the [v4.0.36 Release of ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#v4036-release-notes) that's now available on NuGet.